# How can i use an attribute data-image="something" and data-title="something" in my angular 7 app

Tags: angular

i am working with Shareholic API where users can share different posts, i was given a DIV tag code with some attributes to embed in my angular app, but angular wont allow me use these attributes. please what can i do?
the code is

```
<div class='shareaholic-canvas' data-app='share_buttons' data-app-id="xxxxx" 
     data-title='Page Title' 
     data-link='http://example.com/home.html' 
     data-image='http://example.com/image.jpg' 
     data-summary='Description of the page you are sharing'>
</div>
```

Comment: See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qn1tpx. I copied your code verbatim into an Angular component template, and there's no error at all. So what does "angular wont allow me use these attributes" *precisely* mean? What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: here is the error i ma getting .  compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'link' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: So you probably use `<div link="...">`and not `<div data-link="...">`as you're claiming. Post a complete minimal example reproducting the problem. I just posted one, using the only code you posted, and as you can see, it does not reproduce the error.